# Pulling Google Reviews for a site other than our own

Tags: google-business

Is it possible to display Google Reviews for a company that you don't own the Google My Business profile for?

My company works with local artists - many of whom have their own Google Business page.
They want to show the Google Business reviews on their site, but unless I'm reading the documentation incorrectly, you can only pull reviews for accounts you own and control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have access to their business, you cannot get the reviews via "Google My Business", which makes sense. There is however also the Places API allowing you to request the 5 latest reviews of a business:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details